# Testing element count inside an ng-repeat with protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I want to test that my `ng-repeat` generates more than 1 element.

```
<div ng-repeat="topic in topics">
  <div class="topic-name">{{topic.name}}</div>
</div>
```

How can I do it? I can't find in the docs...
Is there something like this?

```
expect(element.all(by.repeater('topic in topics')).count()).toBeMoreThan(1);
```

Comment: Why can't you count `topics` length?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is located in the Jasmine 2.0 docs, [here](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html). 
Try the following code:

```
var count = element.all(by.repeater('topic in topics'));
count.then(function(result){
    expect(result.length).toBeGreaterThan(1);
});
```

Comment: Won't that error? element.all returns a promise, which won't have a `length` property.

Comment: @Aaron I believe you are correct, I've updated the answer to properly resolve each promise.

Comment: For me it works also with: `expect(element.all(by.repeater('topic in topics').count()).toBeGreaterThan(1)`

Answer (score 4):

While the accepted answer works, it can now be done a lot easier.
You can just do:

```
expect(element.all(by.repeater('topic in topics')).count()).toBeGreaterThan(1);
```